# CentOS 7 VirtualBox no internet access (even after adding DNS1 and modify ONBOOT to yes)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos-7

I installed VirtualBox with an IMAGE of CENTOS 7.5 SERVER.
I'm trying now to enable internet connection there, so I've found my network card name, and then edited the relevant file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts with DNS1=8.8.8.8 and ONBOOT=yes, but I'm still getting an error of 'ip configuration could not be reserved'

Comment: any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

did you turn on Network Bridge or are you trying to run in NAT mode?

With Network Bridge you will get an IP Adress from your allowed DHCP IP Range.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXE3t.png)

Comment: Yes I did. I turn it on and choose Intel(R) Ethernet connection I-129-LM (I didn't had ETC option)

Comment: Can you post your logfile? -

Answer (score 0):

Did you excute command "ifup eth0" for enabling network interface? I have this problem sometimes.

Can you attach result of the command "ifconfig"?

Comment: for ifup command I'm getting: ip configuration could not be reserved